# SQL Server Replications - Objects to include

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

Are there any SQL Server Replication Best Practices?   Are there any links I can read up on?
I’m using 2012 and 2014.  I want to know, in general, what type of database objects typically people replicate
from the source instance (publication) to the target instance (subscription)?  Table is definitely one of them.
If there are a lot of views  associated with the source database and probably not being used in the replicated
database (target/subscription), should I include them in the replication process?  What about stored 
procedures?  In both cases, would it be better just to replicate the data and manually deploy the views and 
stored procedures?   I’d like to get some ideas/suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that cover replication best practices and improving performance:

[Best Practices for Replication Administration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151818.aspx)

[Enhance General Replication Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151791.aspx)

You can find a list of database objects that can be published using Replication here:

[Publish Data and Database Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx)

If the objects are being used at the replicated database (subscriber) then yes, you should replicate the objects.  If not, feel free to exclude them from the publication.

The benefit of including them in the publication, rather than manually deploying them, is that replication supports schema changes to published objects and when you make schema changes on appropriate published objects at the Publisher, those changes are propagated by default to all Subscribers.  This is covered in [Make Schema Changes on Publication Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).

Comment: If the views and stored procedures are not being used at the subscriber, would you still include them?

Comment: I would not include them if they are not being used.

Comment: Thank you.  The links are very helpful as well.